# Is it possible to use session.get() as part of a selector in Meteor event maps?

Tags: meteor

I would like to add specific event only to elements that match a certain criteria, in this case, if the element is selected in the session or not.. Here's some example code:

```
Template.leaderboard.events({
    'click Session.get("selected_team") .win': function () {
        Teams.update(Session.get("selected_team"), {$inc: {won: 1, score : 5, played: 1}});
    }
});
```

This looks for the selected team in the session & then updates that item. Does that make sense? Is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

In the leaderboard example, the selected player is given a css class of "selected", so all you need to do is:

```
Template.player.events({
  'click .selected': function () {
    console.log('clicked on the selected player:', this.name);
  }
});
```

You can use the same pattern for other elements that you might want to trigger events on conditionally: assign a particular css class to them (or not) depending on the condition.

If you prefer not to add a css class to elements through the templates (for whatever reason), you're better off simply checking your condition in Javascript:

```
Template.player.events({
  'click': function () {
    if (Session.get("selected_player") === this._id) {
      console.log('clicked on the selected player:', this.name);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I have used that in one or two places already actually.

Answer (score -1):

It won't work the way you're writing it since you've included the Session.get statement as part of the string. Something like this might work:

```
Template.leaderboard.events({
  'click ' + Session.get("selected_team") + ' .win': function() {}
});
```

...but I wouldn't recommend it. Instead you should probably do something like this:

```
Template.leaderboard.events({
  'click .team': function() {
    Teams.update(this.id, {...});
  }
});

Template.leaderboard.teams = function() {
  return Teams.find({});
}
```

In your view:

```
<template name="leaderboard">
  {{#each teams}}
    <div class="team">{{team}}</div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Each `.team` still remembers its context within the leaderboard template, referred to as `this` inside the event handler, so you can just pass `this.id` to the query.

Comment: Your suggestion does not work actually, it would've been nice. As a selected class is added to the `.team` I used a funky selector: `.selected>.result-change>.win`..